# Using several conditions in SUMIFS using list of elements

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I found a soultion on this site for using several conditions in SUMIFS
But the problem now is I can't make it work on objects/referenses to a list, only when typing in the word/quote "...".

This one works: `=SUM(SUMIFS(C1:C6;A1:A6;1;B1:B6;{"yes";"no"}))`
And this one doesn't: `=SUM(SUMIFS(C1:C6;A1:A6;1;B1:B6;{b8;b9}))`
even though there are no blanks in B8 or B9.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.
 `{}` curly braces indicates an array constant and cell reference cannot be passed to it. 
But if you want to pass multiple Cell Reference as criteria in *Sumifs*, just pass it directly:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C1:C6;A1:A6;1;B1:B6;B8:B9))
```

But for this to work, you have to enter it as *array formula* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you perhaps tell me in what situations/cases Ctrl+Shift+Enter is used? Have never heard of it before

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you want several values for the same range, you could just  repeat the pair:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C1:C6;A1:A6;1;B1:B6;b8;B1:B6;B9)
```